# Websphere MQ Cluster/HQ Sticky session with Queue Managers for synchronized messages

Tags: ibm-mq, high-availability, mq

We have frontend app and backend app deployed in Websphere and communicates thru IBM MQ over JMS (synchronous messages). Now setting up cluster with 2 queue manager in the front end and 2 in the backend applications and configured using JNDI.

When we try to put the message in frontend QMR1, it goes either one of backend and get processed. But the response sometimes goes QMR2 and not always QMR1.

QN: How can we set the paramteres in Websphere MQ / JMS settings to receive the message in from same QMR which we sent .

Please advice.

Comment: Are your reply to queues used to receive responses in the front end QMs clustered as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have clustered the reply queue also. Hence the reply messages are being load balanced between the two front-end queue managers.

One way to send replies to correct destination is not cluster reply queues. Instead define remote queue definition for reply queues in the back-end queue managers. Then use the `replyToQueueManager` attribute of the request message to decide and put the reply message to appropriate reply queue.

For example the following script defines two remote queues in each of two back-end queue managers. The script assumes a queue with name `REPLY_QUEUE` is defined in both front-end queue managers.

```
DEF QREMOTE(REP_Q_FRONT_END_QM1) RNAME(REPLY_QUEUE) RQMNAME(FRONT_END_QM1) CLUSTER(REQUEST_REPLY_CLUSTER)
DEF QREMOTE(REP_Q_FRONT_END_QM2) RNAME(REPLY_QUEUE) RQMNAME(FRONT_END_QM2) CLUSTER(REQUEST_REPLY_CLUSTER)
```

Then the back-end application processing request messages opens the remote queues.

```
MQQueue mqReplyQ_QM1 = queueManager.accessQueue("REP_Q_FRONT_END_QM1", CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT );
MQQueue mqReplyQ_QM2 = queueManager.accessQueue("REP_Q_FRONT_END_QM2", CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT );
```

Then uses `replyToQueueManagerName` attribute to sends reply to correct queue manager.

```
MQMessage msgRequest = new MQMessage();
mqRequestQ.get(msgRequest, mqgmo);                

if(msgRequest.replyToQueueManagerName.trim().equals("FRONT_END_QM1")) {
    mqReplyQ_QM1.put(msgReply);                       
} else {
   mqReplyQ_QM2.put(msgReply);                                                
}
```

There may be better solutions but the above will do the job.